# Dotvvm extension stopped working after update

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, dotvvm

after updating the `dotvvm` extension to `version 1.0.3.3` the extension does not work anymore.

I am getting this error every time I start Visual Studio:

```
LegacySitePackage failed for package [DotvvmPackage]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;DotVVM.VS2015Extension, Version=1.0.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=57a93e56b0609da2&apos; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&apos;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is usually thrown when Visual Studio do not refresh MEF cache.

The solution is to remove content of MEF cache folder.

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```